# Using a javascript "random quote" script but across two separate elements

Tags: javascript, css, random, hyperlink

I'm trying to teach myself a bit of javascript by writing a basic Web site (using Twitter Bootstrap) that presents a random quote from a Project Gutenberg novel, some discussion of it, and then further down the page has a link to go directly to the novel on Project Gutenberg.

I've used this [JavaScript Source script](http://www.javascriptsource.com/miscellaneous/simple-text-rotate.html) to great effect... for the quote itself. But when it comes to linking the second element -- the link to the quoted book -- the text in the button doesn't appear.

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="childquote">
                <p>
                <span id="ran1">&#8220;Quote from a first novel.&#8221;<br>
                - Bram Stoker, <em>Dracula</em></span>
                <span id="ran2">&#8220;Quote from a second novel.&#8221;<br>
                - Herman Melville, <em>Moby Dick</em></span>
```

and later down the page, the button HTML looks like this:

```
 <div class="btn pull-right bookbutton">
                <span id="ran1"><a href="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/345">Read the book</a></span>
                <span id="ran2"><a href="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701">Read the book</a></span>
```

...obviously, all appropriate divs are closed, etc.

The CSS for the page sets display to "none" for all the random options on the page:

```
#ran1,#ran2,#ran3,#ran4,#ran5,#ran6,#ran7,#ran8,#ran9,#ran10,#ran11,#ran12,#ran13,#ran14,#ran15,#ran16,#ran17,#ran18 {
  display:none;
}
```

And the JavaScript itself looks like this:

```
function messageLoad() {

  var wch=Math.floor(Math.random()*18+1);
  document.getElementById('ran'+wch).style.display='inline';
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  messageLoad();
});
```

As far as I understand it, because I don't understand JavaScript **at all**, the JavaScript somehow "deactivates" the "display:none" CSS for a randomly selected "ranXX" so that the first part -- the quote -- will display as though "display:none" was not set for that random number.

But why doesn't this same logic apply on down to the link? I get the random quote just fine, but the button text doesn't appear at all.

Comment: You should definitely replace the css by `.childquote>span,.bookbutton>span{display:none;}` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called `getElementById`, so it will only ever return at most one element. In fact, IDs should be unique on a page - that's the concept of IDs.

You could give the link IDs an affix (say, `ran1link`) so that they *are* uniquely identifiable, and have both elements set their `display` to `inline`.

Note that your `window.onload` trick is not really necessary. There is `addEventListener` which can attach multiple functions to an event. That way you never have clashes with other code adding `onload` functions.

Comment: Thanks, pimvdb -- I understand the problem with getElementById now, even if I don't quite understand your solution.

Would I put a second var inside the function messageload, the first with 'ran' as its variable prefix and the other with 'ranquote' as its prefix, or something like that?

Comment: @mattshepherd: You currently have the line with `getElementById('ran'+wch)` to show the appropriate `ran` item. You could add the same line but with e.g. `getElementById('ranquote'+wch)` to show the link. You'd need to give the link spans an ID like `ranquote1` in that case.